# How to format news, poems, text messages, and other kinds of written text?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, formatting

I always find myself wondering how to format written text: news (on TV and newspapers), text messages (from a cellphone), lyrics, and poems. Right now, I just put them in a new paragraph and italicize them. Example:

**Text Message**

> It occurred to Maria to check her phone for text messages. She went to
>   her purse to get it. There was indeed a message from James. 
>       
>      *My boss just
>   called. One of the freezers broke last night so we have to move all
>   the food to another one before it gets bad. I think I'll spend the
>   whole morning on it. Have breakfast first. I'll call u as soon as I'm
>   done.* 
>     Maria let out a sigh. How could James stand this? She thought
>   his boss
>
> ---

**Poem**

> Taking a bite of her sandwich, Eri pulled her notebook out of her
>   purse, and re-read what she had written yesterday.
>      *Eri, did you feel the earthquake last night? 
>
>      Are you really sure your
>   apartment's alright?*
>      As though they were some kind of secret code, she examined each of the
>   words. Then she fished for pen, and added two more lines.
>      In which planet where you wandering when it came?
>      Is reality and the
>   world as you know still the same?
>      Eri put down her pen and sipped her cup.
>
> ---

**Newspaper**

> Making sure there were no other customers, she brought them back to
>   her sea, and began scanning each headline.
>      *Typhoon Jelawat Kills 62 in
>   Okinawa. Dangerous Toxin Found in Fish for Sale. Price of Rice Raised.
>   Employment Rate Going Down.* Tina folded the newspaper and moved to the
>   next one. *Taxi Collides with Car Causing 5 Deaths. Man Arrested for
>   Trying to Rob a McDonald's. Temperatures forecast to be higher than
>   average for Aug-Sept. Woman Finds Hat in a Tree.*
>      By the time Tina was
>   done, she had read nearly forty headlines.

I looked around Google and some say one should use block quotes. What's the conventional way of formatting these things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not really come across any conventional way of formatting these things. Much of the (rest of my answer) is based on my readings and a few other sources (which I will be citing).

The short answer first: yes, use block quotes. Solves most of the problems. Keep the following in mind for blockquotes:

- Indent the content (usually 1 inche)
- Doublespace
- Do not include quotation marks

The MLA Guideline for using block quotes can be found here: http://writingcommons.org/format/mla/621-follow-mla-guidelines-for-block-quotations

The long answer:

For **text messages**, use any of the following strategies:

- *Italicize* the text message
- Underline the text message (a little more distracting than italics)
- Use a different font than the main text (for example, use Courier instead of regular serifs)

In either case, you would have to do the following too: (essentially making it a block quote)

- Make sure the content is in a new paragraph
- Make sure the content is indented (usually 1 inch)

For **poems** and **lyrics**, use the following:

The following is based on a book *The Agony and the Ecstasy* by *Irving Stone* which includes poems in the middle of the text (was reading the book, so have used it as a reference).

- Indent the poem 1 inch from the main text (so if you have a margin of 1 inch, the total indentation for the poem becomes 1+1 inches)
- Use the same line spacing as the main text
- Use the same font as the main text
- Include an extra space before and after the poem. For example, it is a usual practice not to include double Enter between paragraphs. However, in this case, include a double paragraph (both before and after).

For **newspaper**: (have not found any authoritative source for this)

- If it is just the headline(s) that you are quoting, you can simply italicize them in the main body
- If you need to include a newspaper clipping, use block quotes

A few other points:

- The decision to use a different font is generally by the publisher. You can insist that they use a different font for a particular type of content (for example, Instant Messages or text messages)
- In certain books, the content is center aligned, so I believe it is something that has got more to do with the publishing house than a convention (for example, *The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Nighttime* by *Mark Haddon*)

Hope these help!

Comment: I'm pretty much in agreement except for underlines. You should *only* use underlines for hyperlinks, never for emphasis.

Comment: @Pravesh Parekh My paragraphs are formatted as 0.25 inches. That means I have to leave the poem as 1.25?

Comment: @AlexandroChen Do you mean that your paragraphs (main text) has the left/right margin as 0.25 inches? In that case, the poem would have the margin as 1.25

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting topic. I'm not seeing any set conventions for this either, but with the advent of e-books, the formatting vagaries bring up new issues. Because the book will be read on a variety of e-readers, and users can vary the reading experience, you can't depend on block text or different fonts to render properly in all situations. So, if you're editing for an e-book, perhaps begin the text in a new paragraph and introduce with an em dash or hyphen? Or use italics, unless you're using italics for so many other situations that you might be confusing the reader.